# Penalising - but not eliminating duplicates - in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, duplicates

I have some data with duplicate fields. I don't want duplicates to appear together on top of search results, but I don't want to eliminate them altogether. I just want to get a better variety, so the 2nd, 3rd ... nth occurrence of the same field-value would be demoted. Is that possible with ElasticSearch?

For example:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/employeeid/info/1' -d '{
 "name": "John",
 "organisation": "Apple",
 "importance": 1000
}'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/employeeid/info/2' -d '{
 "name":"John",
 "organisation":"Apple",
 "importance": 2000
 }'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/employeeid/info/3' -d '{
 "name": "Sam",
 "organisation": "Apple",
 "importance": 0
 }'
```

(based on [this](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch))

If we assume search is boosted by importance, the natural result for "Apple" search would be `John`, `John`, `Sam`. What I am looking for is a way to make the result `John`, `Sam`, `John`, ie penalise the second `John` because another `John` has already appeared.

Comment: I believe the possible solution is using scripts and scoring: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html , https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust the importance field at index time by finding all duplicates and choosing one of the duplicates to be 'more important' - maybe the duplicate with the highest score is chosen. From your example, I would add 5000 to the existing value of importance.

The results would now rank as follows.

John/Apple-7000, Sam/Apple-5000, John/Apple-1000

But this means you would need to re-index if you decided to change the 5000 to 10000 to adjust the scoring as it depends on the magnitude of importance.

Alternatively, you could add another field called 'authority' for which you could give a value of 1 for the duplicate with the highest importance and use a scoring function to provide a step at query-time :-

```
"script_score": {
   "script": "(_score * 5000) + doc['importance'].value + (doc['authority'].value * 5000)"
}
```

Note that the multiplier for _score depends on the original ranking algorithm, this assumes a value for _score from 0.0 to 1.0

Comment: _score is bound between 0 and 1, do you think it would have such relevance in your computation with the 'authority' field?

Comment: thanks. good point - I can adjust and add a note about _score as it depends on the original scoring algorithm.

Comment: Thanks. I hope there's a more direct way in the future, but some extra indexing work like this could do it.